# How to include value from one function in another?

Tags: jquery, function, variables

I based below code on a few answers here, but I'm a real noob in jQuery, so I would appreciate any help.

I want to create a Lightbox popup, but the website is on Wordpress, so I need to add id's dynamically to HTML markup.

I was able to add numbers to ids in order to differentiate them, but I have difficulty with implementing those dynamic ids inside variables `btnPhotos` and `galleryItems`. Any ideas how to do that?

```
// Gallery lightbox

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  // Add numbers to ids
  var n = 0;
  $(".card_image img").each(function(n) {
        n++;
        $(this).attr("id", "gallery-popup-" + n);
  });

  $(".cards > div").each(function(n) {
        n++;
        $(this).attr("id", "gallery-" + n);
  });

  // use above variables to trigger lightbox
  var btnPhotos = $("#gallery-popup"),
    galleryItems = $("#gallery").find(".gallery-item a");

  $("#gallery-popup").click(function(event) {
    galleryItems.first().click();
  });

});
```

Right now `btnPhotos` is lokking for `#gallery-popup`, but there's no `#gallery-popup` as in the first function I'm adding counter to every `#gallery-popup`. 
So in HTML markup it results in

`#gallery-popup-1`

`#gallery-popup-2` etc...

How to use this "updated" HTML markup in `var btnPhotos`, so it looks for `#gallery-popup-1`, `#gallery-popup-2` and so on?

The same story is with `galleryItems`, which is looking for `#gallery`, but the markup changed with the counters is:

`#gallery-1`

`#gallery-2` etc

Below is the markup I get (please note that these are Wordpress posts, so the number of `id="gallery-` and `id="gallery-popup-` is changing...

```
 <ul class="cards"> 

   <li class="cards_item">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card_image">
            <img id="gallery-popup-1" src="image01.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card_content">
            <h3 class="card_heading">Title here</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div id="gallery-1">
    <ul>
      <li class="gallery-item">
          <a href="image01.png" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1409106488" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="779"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        </li>                                                    
    </ul>
  </div> 

  <li class="cards_item">
    <div class="card">
         <div class="card_image">
               <img id="gallery-popup-2" src="image02.png">
         </div>
        <div class="card_content">
             <h3 class="card_heading">Title here</h3>
        </div>
     </div>
  </li>           
  <div id="gallery-2">
    <ul>
      <li class="gallery-item">
         <a href="image02.png" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="290324284" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="776"><img src="" alt=""></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</ul>
```

I'm not sure if it's needed, but just in case, here's also the code from the template file, which is responsible for the markup above:

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>          
    <li class="cards_item">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card_image">
                 <?php                            
                      $url = wp_get_attachment_url( 
                      get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>
                      <img id="gallery-popup" src="<?php echo $url ?>"/>
                      </div>
                        <div class="card_content">
                           <h3 class="card_heading"><?php 
                           the_title();?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </li>

              <?php $images = get_field('gallery_images');
                if( $images ): ?>
                <div id="gallery">
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): 
                            $content = '<li class="gallery-item">';
                                $content .= '<a href="'. 
                                $image['url'] .'">';
                                $content .= '<img src="'. 
                                $image['sizes']['full'] .'" alt="'. $image['alt'] .'" />';
                                $content .= '</a>';
                                $content .= '</li>';
                            if ( function_exists('slb_activate') ){
                    $content = slb_activate($content);
                    }

                echo $content;?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: What is the relationship you are looking for? Not really enough known

Comment: Hi, sorry I updated my question, so maybe it's more clear right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the dynamic ids in an array and use the array as a selector...

```
// Gallery lightbox

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // Add numbers to ids
  var n = 0;
  var photoIdList = []; // create an array to store the dynamic ids
  var itemsIdList = [];
  $(".card_image img").each(function(n) {
        n++;
        const id = "gallery-popup-" + n;
        photoIdList.push(id); // push the ids into the array
        $(this).attr("id", id);
  });

  $(".cards > div").each(function(n) {
        n++;
        const id = "gallery-" + n;
        itemsIdList.push(id);
        $(this).attr("id", id);
  });

  // use above variables to trigger lightbox
  var btnPhotos = $(photoIdList), // use the array as the selector
    galleryItems = $(itemsIdList).find(".gallery-item a");

  $(photoIdList).click(function(event) {
    galleryItems.first().click();
  });

});
```

But it would probably make more sense to use the selector syntax for `attribute "id" starts with` instead...

```
// Gallery lightbox

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  // Add numbers to ids
  var n = 0;
  $(".card_image img").each(function(n) {
        n++;
        $(this).attr("id", "gallery-popup-" + n);
  });

  $(".cards > div").each(function(n) {
        n++;
        $(this).attr("id", "gallery-" + n);
  });

  // use above variables to trigger lightbox
  var btnPhotos = $("[id^=gallery-popup-]"), // just modify your selector to target the dynamic ids
    galleryItems = $("[id^=gallery-]").find(".gallery-item a");

  btnPhotos.click(function(event) {
    galleryItems.first().click();
  });

});
```

If you could share your markup structure, you might get a better answer.

---

**EDIT**
Also, as rightly pointed out by [@martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2519416/martijn), your `id` setter routine should probably look a lot more like this:

```
let n = 0;
$(".card_image img").each(function() {
      this.id = "gallery-popup-" + n++;
});

// or even easier, each() has it's own counter:
$(".card_image img").each(function(index) {
      this.id = "gallery-popup-" + index;
});
```

**EDIT**:
Given your markup, I'd recommend the following:

```
// Gallery lightbox
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".card_image img").each(function(index) {
        this.id = "gallery-popup-" + index;
    });

    $(".cards > div").each(function(index) {
        this.id = "gallery-" + index;
    });

    // use event delegation to catch click events and trigger others.
    $(".cards").on("click", "[id^=gallery-popup-]", function (e) {
        var item = '#' + this.id.replace('-popup', ''); // `this` should refer to the gallery-popup
        $(item).find(".gallery-item a").first().click();
    });
});
```

Comment: To set /get id's, please just use `this.id` :) Also you can move the n++ to the setter instead of a line just for a incrementer, creating cleaner code :)

Comment: I agree that it would be cleaner, but when answering questions, I generally try to modify the code as little as possible so that the OP is able to see the differences more easily. Edited answer to include that feedback.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer - your updated code (second option with @Martijn hint) loads the lightbox correctly. The problem is that it always shows the content from the id="gallery-popup-1", even if I click on id="gallery-popup-2" , 3 etc. So I'm not sure if I should look for the answer in jQuery or rather in Wordpress markup (which I guess, is out of scope on that forum)..

Comment: You'll probably want to change your selector for `galleryItems` then... if you could share some example HTML markup, I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've added another snippet, each has it's own counter, so you don't need a `n++`

Comment: @Martijn Thank you, that looks crystal clear ;) I've updated my question with HTML markup and a Wordpress loop responsible for it...

Comment: Thanks @pete I've just checked your code -> I think you made a typo in a line:     this.id = "gallery-" + index);    because ) throws unexpected token error. But even after removing that, now the code doesn't load lightbox at all :(

Comment: @Anda mistakes were made (primarily I forgot the `#` part of the selector. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks so much @pete ! It works perfectly now! I'll be happy to upvote your answer as soon as I get required amount of reputation points:)